How to fetch Discord messages via a user token
I'm looking to develop a Rust application that "listens" to messages posted on Discord channels and writes them to me in STDOUT. I don't want to use a bot because it doesn't (and won't) have access to the channels. So I try to use my own user token (obtained via the "authorization" field in network requests). I don't want to use websockets because they don't return ALL posted messages.
I get the following error: Client error: Gateway(InvalidAuthentication)
Here is the code :
cargo.toml
[package]
name = "upgradifier"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.204"
serde_derive = "1.0.204"
serenity = "0.12.2"
tokio = { version = "1.38.0", features = ["full"] }
toml = "0.8.14"

main.rs
use config::*;
use event::*;
use serenity::{all::GatewayIntents, Client};

#[allow(unused)]

mod event;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main()
{
    const USER_TOKEN: &str = "MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN";
    let config = load_config();
    let handler = Handler { channel: "1170190720754274415" };
    let mut client = Client::builder(USER_TOKEN, GatewayIntents::GUILD_MESSAGES)
        .event_handler(handler)
        .await
        .expect("Error creating client");

    if let Err(why) = client.start().await {
        println!("Client error: {:?}", why);
    }
}

event.rs
use serenity::{async_trait, model::{channel::Message, gateway::Ready}, prelude::*};
pub struct Handler {
    pub channel: &str,
}

#[async_trait]
impl EventHandler for Handler {
    async fn message(&self, _ctx: Context, msg: Message) {
        if self.channel == &msg.channel_id.to_string() {
            println!("{}: {}", msg.author.name, msg.content);
        }
    }

    async fn ready(&self, _: Context, ready: Ready) {
        println!("{} is connected!", ready.user.name);
    }
}

Can you help me solve this problem?

Please first reduce your problem; is the issue still there when you hard-code the values into your main()? If so, the config loading is irrelevant and can be removed.

Then, as @kmdreko said, please remove that part from the question. Create a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Reproducible, yes, but not minimal. Please remove the config reading.

@ChayimFriedman Done.
